# Start jar service on ports belong to Apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, java, dedicated-server, service

I have been made a service for my Android Game. The service have socket connection, that connection is open on port `4444`. My android App has connected with server by IP address e.g. `192.168.1.1:4444` and then exchange data. I have been using socket because I need real time connection.

The problem is a lot of public place with WiFi and some home access point have open small range of port e.g. `80, 443, 3128, 8080`. Port `4444` is closed.

When users are downloading my App they have been thinking it doesn't work.

My question is, it's possible to configure Apache on dedicated server and start my App service on e.g. `22` or `443` port? I'm not using SSH and HTTPS.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use HTTPS (Port 443) on the machine, binding *any* other service to this port shouldn't be a problem.

The same is true for every port: If it's not in use, you can bind any other process to it.

Comment: Thanks! Should I firstly turn it of in Apache or somewhere?

Comment: If it is activated and configured in Apache, you need to turn it off. In that case, binding to port 443 would fail anyway.